# ExtJS - How to automatically scroll to a form field?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, extjs, extjs4

I need to scroll to a form field (a `displayfield` actually) automatically. Since the field is dynamic, sometimes it is already shown in the rendered area of page, sometimes it is not.

How can I do this using `ExtJS 4.x`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `focus()` on the desired `displayfield` :

```
<yourDisplayField>.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollTo` function of Ext dom element. [Reference](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-scrollTo)

> **scrollTo( side, value, [animate] )** -> Scrolls this element the
>   specified scroll point.

Parameters

- **side** : String (Either "left" for scrollLeft values or "top" for scrollTop values.)
- **value** : Number(The new scroll value)
- **animate** : Boolean/Object (optional) (true for the default animation
  or a standard Element animation config object)

Add following lines of code to the form panel.

```
 listeners:{
        afterrender: function(){            
            this.body.el.scrollTo('top',200,true);
        }
    },
```

Comment: have already tried it; did not work for me. here is the sample code snippet: `field.getEl().scrollTo('top', 200, true);`

Comment: You have to call the scrollTo function of dom element of the container. Something like this - `field.up('panel').scrollTo('top',200,true);`

Comment: still did not work; the container is a `formpanel`. `form.getEl().scrollTo('top',200,true);` tried with various `value` parameter

Comment: Talha, I have added code. I think the scroll should be applied to the body element. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @Glisha for your care; even though I use `Ext.getBody().el.scrollTo('top',1100,true);` nothing changes. By the way another issue is determining the `value` automatically in order to scroll the related field.

Comment: Please check this fiddle. It seems to be working fine. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11o2

Comment: And I think if you know the height used for each item in the form-panel, you can easily find the position of the required displayfield.

Comment: that makes sense but I think there must be a built-in way for that. You know the position of the field can be changed through the browser and/or also user preferences. So it would be better to manage scroll by reference instead of height calculation similar to navigators used with Bootstrap or jQuery.